# Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application after the activity is already created

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load progressBar as dialog while the client app send some data to server and dismiss the bar when data is received back from server.The below code has implemented this model.. with and interface being implemented inside an activity.

```
private void setup(){
    ConnectionHandler connectionHandler = new ConnectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSendData(){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this);
                    Log.d("progress bar", "getData: true" );
                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading..");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        public void onReceiveData(List<Model> model) {
            //do nothing for now
            LoginMessage message = (LoginMessage)model.get(0);
            if(message.getUserCode() != 0){
                //registration successfull prompt to verify code;
                Log.d("LoginMessage", "onListUpdate: " + message.toJson());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), VerificationActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.login_message),message.toJson());
                intent.putExtra("email", credentials.getEmail());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                //something went wrong;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Model> getType() {
            return LoginMessage.class;
        }
    };
    connectivity = new Connectivity(this, Properties.LOCALHOST + Properties.REGISTRATION_PHP);
    connectivity.setConnectionHandler(connectionHandler);
}
```

The setup method is called when activity is created and connectivity is responsible for calling the onSendData() and onReceiveData().Everything was working fine untill i decided to have progressBar to make client wait for the data to load. Here the error is thrown saying `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window` -- token null is not for an application. I followed the solution shown in the other similar problem but didn't worked for me.
Some advised to use

```
 progressBar = new ProgressBar(Activity.this) instead of 
 progressBar = new ProgressBar(getApplicationContext()) or new ProgressBar(getBaseContext)
```

but none of them worked for me.What is this error actually is saying to me.
Why is this error thrown?? please help

Comment: I have no more idea but you can not add one thread in side another thread. So please use AsyncTask to achieve what you want

Comment: i am using handler to update UI instead of AsyncTask.If i have to go with AsyncTask i need to change my whole project, which is a mess. Do you have any solution on this model..

Comment: are u adding this code in a dialog or activity?

Comment: No, if you can use AsyncTask then it's work like one separate class, It will not affect your UI

Comment: Am i running a thread inside a thread. No i am not.. i am supplying a runnable to run on UI thread.

Comment: W4R10CK i am adding this code in activity..

Comment: please share your whole activity code here http://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: here is the url http://paste.ofcode.org/HfezKMef8SKd59YnvbWFJh